# How can i fetch data from another table referenced by foreign key?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

Heres my tables that a wanna fetch the data, i am using express to make a get request from the next app:

```
model Provider {
  id          String    @id @default(cuid())
  name        String
  email       String
  password    String
  phone       String      
  photo       String?
  service     Service?  @relation(fields: [serviceId], references: [id])
  serviceId   String?
  location    Location? @relation(fields: [locationId], references: [id])
  locationId  String?
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  text        String
  starAverage Float
  medals      Medals[]
  comment     Comment[]
}

model Service {
  id       String     @id @default(cuid())
  type     String
  provider Provider[]
}
```

I wanna fetch the type of the service of the services table of a provider, not the serviceId, and this is my route.

```
router.get('/list', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const allClients = await prisma.client.findMany()
  res.json({allClients})
})
```

this is how i am fetching the data of the rest API using axios

```
const [providers, setProviders] = useState([] as any[])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5140/providers/list')//my list of all providers
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      setProviders(res.data)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }, )
  const renderedProviders = Object.values(providers).map(provider => {
    return (
      <div
        className="card"
        style={{ width: "18rem"}}
        key={provider.id}
      >
        <img className="card-img-top" src="..."/>
        <div className="card-body">
          <h3>{provider.name}</h3>
          <p>{provider.starAverage} estrekas</p>
          <p>{provider.serviceId}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-between">
      {renderedProviders}
    </div>
  )
```

for now a only get the serviceId of a provider, not the type of the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch data from another table referenced by a foreign key in a database, you can use a `JOIN` clause in your SQL query. A JOIN clause allows you to combine rows from two or more tables based on a related column between the tables.

this how you can use a `JOIN` clause to fetch data from two tables, `users` and `orders`, that are related by a foreign key.

```
SELECT users.*, orders.*
FROM users
JOIN orders ON orders.user_id = users.id
```

the `JOIN` clause combines rows from the `users` and `orders` tables based on the `user_id` column in the `orders` table and the `id` column in the `users` table. The `SELECT` clause specifies the columns to be retrieved from the `users` and `orders` tables.

**Edited**
how you can reference this in the express route and in the http request from axios ?

you can use the sequelize.query(Sequelize is a promise-based Node.js ORM) method to execute a raw SQL query.

```
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const query = `
    SELECT users.*, orders.*
    FROM users
    JOIN orders ON orders.user_id = users.id
    WHERE users.id = :id
  `;
  const replacements = { id };
  sequelize.query(query).then(([results, metadata]) => {
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

the sequelize.query method is used to execute a raw SQL query that includes a JOIN clause to fetch data from the users and orders tables.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i reference this in the express route and in the http request from axios?

Comment: @PedrodeSouza I edited the answer take a look that might help.

Comment: Thanks! I will test it later and see if it works, and i am using Prisma as my ORM, so i dont know if it would be the same

Comment: I solved, i use include in the express route and it works, thanks anyway